# displaying maximum difference between arrays as a list

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 two-dimensional arrays, where each row represents a time and each column represents an item. I want to find the maximum difference between the two arrays for each item. (I don't particularly care about finding where in time that greatest difference is at this point.)

I want to create a list of these maximum differences so that later I can find the largest 15 of that list.

So far, I've tried to accomplish this task by doing something this:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
array2 = [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]]

num_items = np.shape(array1)[1]
num_timesteps = np.shape(array1)[0]

for counter in np.arange(0, num_items):
    for counter2 in np.arange(0, num_timesteps):
        diff_list = []
        diff = array1[counter2][counter] - array2[counter2][counter]
        diff = abs(diff)
        diff_list.append(diff)
    max_diff = []
    max_diff.append(max(diff_list))
    print max_diff
```

However, this doesn't print an actual list. Instead, it gives me one list per item with the maximum difference for that item.

Desired output: [2, 2, 0, 4, 10]

Current output: [2] [2] [0] [4] [10]

So, my question is: How can I find the maximum differences between my two arrays and put them in a single list?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want for output, can you give desired output for the data you have?

Comment: Use `abs(np.subtract(array1,array2))`. The function `abs()` is used to avoid negative numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `max_diff = []` outside of the for loop in order to get your required output. This would lead to the following code:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
array2 = [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]]

num_items = np.shape(array1)[1]
num_timesteps = np.shape(array1)[0]
max_diff= []  #moves this outside of the for loop
for counter in np.arange(0, num_items):
    for counter2 in np.arange(0, num_timesteps):
        diff_list = []
        diff = array1[counter2][counter] - array2[counter2][counter]
        diff = abs(diff)
        diff_list.append(diff)

    max_diff.append(max(diff_list))
    print (max_diff)
```

> Output: [2, 2, 0, 4, 10]

Comment: This worked exactly the way I wanted it to once I moved the print statement out of the for loop as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How about using `np.subtract` you're missing the point of using numpy while you create loop iterators.

Not 100% sure if this works since I don't have numpy installed but here's code:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
array2 = [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]]
array1, array2 = np.asarray(array1), np.asarray(array2)

diff = np.subtrat(array1, array2)
diff = np.absolute(diff)

print diff.max()
```

Comment: Or even just ```diff = a-b; result = diff.max(0), np.absolute(result, result)```

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehention you can do :

```
a=[abs(b-c) for x,y in zip(array1,array2) for b,c in zip(x,y)]
```

> output : [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 2, 2, 0, 4, 10]

Edit: you just want the last one so :

```
a=[abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(array1[2],array2[2])]
```

> output : [2, 2, 0, 4, 10]

this is a bit slower than numpy operation but for this size it shouldn't be a problem.